# How to get all entities from a foreign key that points to an entity in the same table, reiterative?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Movie table and a movie can have a previous_part. Now I would like to, for example, based on movie_id '412331' get all the movies as shown in the image with the Star Wars movies. Is this possible with SQL(MsSQL/AzureSql)?

I am sorry for the lack of information, but I have honestly no idea on how to even start making a SQL query with this problem.

[image: movies]

Update:

Created a Recursive Query, but it only works if I give the movie that starts it all (see `WHERE Prev.previous_part = 412332` in the code block). So in this example Episode V would return the other two movies and Episode VI would only return Episode VII.

```
With MovieList AS
    (SELECT Prev.movie_id, Prev.title, Prev.description, Prev.previous_part, 1 as PrevLevel
    FROM Movie as Prev
    WHERE Prev.previous_part = 412332

    UNION ALL

    SELECT Mov.movie_id, Mov.title, Mov.description, Mov.previous_part, ML.PrevLevel + 1
    FROM Movie as Mov
    INNER JOIN MovieList AS ML
    ON Mov.previous_part = ML.movie_id
    WHERE Mov.previous_part IS NOT NULL)
SELECT * FROM MovieList
```

Comment: [Recursive Queries Using Common Table Expressions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx]).

Comment: I love how the prequels don't exist here :)

Given you have a publication_year, though, perhaps you want a field named something like `franchise`, `family`, or `series` instead, and then just show the records that have the same series value (if any) in publication order.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn The problem is that I am working with an existing database that is built like this. The movie table even has around 380000 records.

Comment: Try to follow @Igor's recommendations and DIY. This is not a kind of rocket science. And Let The Force Be With You.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev I will do my best.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev I have followed it, but the current query I made only works if the given movie_id to start with is the first one from the franchise.

Comment: Your attempt is not bad. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Recursive CTE you need:

```
;with ml as (
--this is Anckor Query
select movie_id, title, previous_part
from movie where movie_id = 412325
union all
--this is Recursive Query
select m.movie_id, m.title, m.previous_part
from movie m
inner join ml on ml.previous_part = m.movie_id --link current prev to parent id
--if you want sequels instead of prev's change to m.previous_part = ml.movie_id
)
select * from ml
```

Answer (score 0):

@Igors comment is correct recursive queries if there are multiple levels of reference/heirarchy you can use a recursive common table expression.  Microsoft has a good Manager/Employee example.  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx

That may be way more complicated than what you are looking for it is a little unclear.

If it is just one level of reference meaning you don't have to match then match again and again to find everything you want you can just use a Self Referencing outer join.

```
SELECT *
FROM
    dbo.movies m1
    LEFT JOIN dbo.movies m2
    ON m1.movied_id = m2.previous_part
WHERE
    m1.title LIKE '%Star Wars%'
    OR m2.movied_ID IS NOT NULL
    OR m2.title LIKE '%Star Wars%'
```

Good first stab I think you are close.  Without your dataset it is a little hard to try but here is an edit that should give you a full list of every movie and their level.

```
;With MovieList AS (
    SELECT Prev.movie_id, Prev.title, Prev.description, Prev.previous_part, 1 as PrevLevel
    FROM Movie as Prev
    WHERE Prev.previous_part IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT Mov.movie_id, Mov.title, Mov.description, Mov.previous_part, ML.PrevLevel + 1
    FROM Movie as Mov
    INNER JOIN MovieList AS ML
    ON Mov.previous_part = ML.movie_id
)
SELECT * FROM MovieList
```

Note you can add a where statement on your `SELECT * FROM MovieList` to limit the list however you want after you generate the hierarchy.

Comment: Unfortunately I do have to match then match again and again.

Comment: The MS link posted will get you there just think of previous_part as Manager in the example and movie_id as Employee.  SQLauthority also has a good perhaps slightly easier to digest article on the same subject. http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/04/24/sql-server-introduction-to-hierarchical-query-using-a-recursive-cte-a-primer/

Comment: I have followed it, but the current query I made only works if the given movie_id to start with is the first one from the franchise. So the earliest movie_id.

Comment: Got it, your Prev.previous_part = 412332 should be Prev.previous_part IS NULL.  That will return all top level movies first and you shouldn't need your where statement in the recursive section.  I will edit my post with code to try.

Answer (score 0):

this seems to solve your question.

```
select * 
into #t
from (
select 123 id,'xxx'nm,1234 pid
union all
select 1234, 'xl',12345
union all 
select 12345,'xlxl',123456
) x

declare @mid int = 123

select x.* from #t x
where x.id = @mid

union all

select y.* from #t x
left join #t y
on x.pid = y.id
where x.id = @mid

union all

select z.* from #t x
left join #t y
on x.pid = y.id
left join #t z
on y.pid = z.id
left join #t xx
on z.pid = xx.id
where x.id = @mid

union all

select xx.* from #t x
left join #t y
on x.pid = y.id
left join #t z
on y.pid = z.id
left join #t xx
on z.pid = xx.id
where x.id = @mid
```

this query pulls up to 4 movies, but you can add more following the logic.
also it only works if you search by the earliest movie id.
if you need it to search both ways this should work

```
declare @mid int = 12345

select distinct * from 
(
select x.* from #t x
where x.id = @mid

union all

select y.* from #t x
left join #t y
on x.pid = y.id or  x.id = y.pid
where x.id = @mid

union all

select z.* from #t x
left join #t y
on x.pid = y.id or x.id = y.pid
left join #t z
on y.pid = z.id or y.id = z.pid 
where x.id = @mid

union all

select xx.* from #t x
left join #t y
on x.pid = y.id  or x.id = y.pid
left join #t z
on y.pid = z.id or y.id = z.pid 
left join #t xx
on z.pid = xx.id or z.id = xx.pid
where x.id = @mid

) x
```